# APBill web service issue

Tags: acumatica

I'm consuming the web service to create an AP Bills and Adjustments record, and it goes ok until I try to set the DocType ("Type").  If I leave it to default to 'Bill', I have no problem.  If I try setting the dropdown explicitly to 'Bill' (or 'Debit Adj.', or 'Credit Adj.') I get an error that tells me the Save has been disabled (Error occurs on the Save).  I've looked in the system and I cannot find anywhere where 'Bill' exists - only 'INV' in the db.  Looking at the source code, I can see an attribute on the Type dropdown called [ARInvoiceType.List()], but I can't find its contents.  If you look at the APDocType enumeration, it doesn't show 'Bill' anywhere either.  I've tried setting the Type to 'INV' and 'Invoice' - and that doesn't work either.  I need to know what to set the 'Type' to in the web service so that it represents what the dropdown shows.

Here is the relevant code sample:

```
            foreach (PXResult<xvwInterCompanyProcess> rec in res)
            {

                xvwInterCompanyProcess icp = (xvwInterCompanyProcess)rec;

                //Set the Doc Type...
                apDocType = "Bill";
              //Save if the RefNbr has changed - unless it's the first record...
                if (icp.OrigRefNbr != LastRefNbr)
                {
                    if (Counter > 0) context.Submit(new Command[] { AP301000.Actions.Save });

                    //Insert...
                    context.Submit(new Command[] { AP301000.Actions.Insert });

                    //add the Header records...
                    context.Submit(
                        new Command[]
                            {
                                //First, the header records...
                                new Value { Value = apDocType, LinkedCommand = AP301000.DocumentSummary.Type },
                                new Value { Value = Convert.ToString(icp.DocDate), LinkedCommand = AP301000.DocumentSummary.Date },
                                new Value { Value = icp.VendorRef, LinkedCommand = AP301000.DocumentSummary.VendorRef },
                                new Value { Value = icp.Description, LinkedCommand = AP301000.DocumentSummary.Description },
                                new Value { Value = "ZINTERREC", LinkedCommand = AP301000.DocumentSummary.Vendor },
                            }
                       );
                }

                //add the detail records...
                context.Submit(
                    new Command[]
                    {
                        AP301000.DocumentDetails.ServiceCommands.NewRow,  
                        new Value { Value = icp.InventoryID, LinkedCommand = AP301000.DocumentDetails.InventoryID },
                        new Value { Value = icp.TranDesc, LinkedCommand = AP301000.DocumentDetails.TransactionDescr },
                        new Value { Value = Convert.ToString(icp.Qty), LinkedCommand = AP301000.DocumentDetails.Quantity },
                        new Value { Value = icp.Uom, LinkedCommand = AP301000.DocumentDetails.UOM },
                        new Value { Value = Convert.ToString(icp.Units), LinkedCommand = AP301000.DocumentDetails.UnitCost },
                        new Value { Value = Convert.ToString(icp.TranAmt), LinkedCommand = AP301000.DocumentDetails.ExtCost },
                        new Value { Value = icp.Account, LinkedCommand = AP301000.DocumentDetails.Account },
                        new Value { Value = icp.APProject, LinkedCommand = AP301000.DocumentDetails.Project },
                        new Value { Value = icp.Aptask, LinkedCommand = AP301000.DocumentDetails.ProjectTask },
                        new Value { Value = "NONTAXABLE", LinkedCommand = AP301000.DocumentDetails.TaxCategory },
                        new Value { Value = "2", LinkedCommand = AP301000.DocumentDetails.SourceCompany },
                        new Value { Value = "Acumatica", LinkedCommand = AP301000.DocumentDetails.SourceApplication },
                        new Value { Value = "AR", LinkedCommand = AP301000.DocumentDetails.SourceModule },
                        new Value { Value = icp.OrigRefNbr + "|" + icp.LineNbr, LinkedCommand = AP301000.DocumentDetails.SourceID },

                        //new Value { Value = "US000000000", LinkedCommand = AP301000.DocumentDetails.Subaccount },
                    }
                    );

                LastRefNbr = icp.OrigRefNbr;
                Counter++;

            }
            if (res.Count > 0)
                context.Submit(new Command[] { AP301000.Actions.Save });
  }
```

I'll try to set the 'Type' before the insert command...

Comment: Would help if you could include a detailed code sample

Comment: The value you will set will be the value you see in UI. Also set the Type first and then the Schema.Actions.Insert command after that before you set the rest of the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the 'Type' BEFORE you submit an insert command.

Comment: Thanks, Hybridzz - that did it. I had no idea you had to set the 'Type' BEFORE the Insert command is initated